# I2C to IrDA - any pitfalls?

Tags: i2c, infrared

I need to operate a peripheral chip via bidirectional I2C across a significant air gap (30mm) and powered wirelessly. Has anyone done the I2C to IrDA? Any problems? Any better solutions?

I want to connect with a remotely powered board carrying the chip. Air gap is what it says - no wired connection for power or signals

Comment: Bi-directionally? Data Speed? Power requirements?

Comment: I²C  requires two bidirectional signals. This sounds like a job for an UART.

Comment: @Andyaka Bidirectional, 115kB as per IrDA spec, power < 100mA. Looking at http://www.nxp.com/products/interface-and-connectivity/interface-and-system-management/bridges/i2c-spi-slave-to-uart-irda-gpio-bridges:MC_51852

Comment: 115 kB is presumably 115 k Bytes per second (capital B means bytes). What is speed in both directions and do you definitely need to be IIC because getting clocks and data in both directions is quite problematic.

Comment: When you say "powered wirelessly" do you mean that the I2C chip needs to be powered across a gap of 30mm? That seems to be a bigger problem then getting a wireless data communication across 30mm. how much power does it need? What approaches are you considering for power, as this might influence the data comms approach. Is this for small/medium quantity or large-scale production?

Comment: @gbulmer It's totally airgapped and all power and data must be wireless. Power supply requirements are likely to be much less than 100mA, 5V. Power supply is resonant transfer inductive coupling

Comment: IMHO, it would be worth adding that to your question. I assume that is why you want to use optical communications? Do the two parts of the system move w.r.t. one another, or are they in a fixed relationship?

Comment: I've used SPI to send data via IR and we could isolate the transmissions between sending and receiving by using different IR frequency pairs for MOSI and MISO.  The /CS line was another one.  Our initial prototype had an issue with reflection.  In retrospect, we should have just purchased some IR serial chip sets and modified everything to fit those nicely, but sometimes you don't think too far down on the software side.

Comment: I think it would be worth updating the question with the link to the NXP part. A member of the community has spent time answering, while those NXP parts seem to avoid the issues mentioned in their answer. Those NXP parts appear to do everything you need, and so the question appears to be asking if that sort of chip has problems.

Comment: Can the optical communication path be shielded from external light sources? I haven't figured out how the NXP parts deal with external light interference, but if that is not an issue it is irrelevant.

Comment: @gbulmer If I mentioned a specific part in the question it would be closed by the moderators. Had that happen before

Comment: @DirkBruere - sorry, yes that may happen. It may be worth trying to edit the question and add it after a day or two. So far people are not looking at the NXP part, so you aren't getting much information. Have you used the NXP parts before? I've not noticed them before.

Comment: Can you add to the question a link or part number for the I2C chip?

Answer (score 1):

I2C has nearly no protocol requirements.  While IrDA is has a complex protocol requirement:

[image]

Consider if the benefits of the IrDA protocol outweigh the costs of implementing it.

If this is a clean (you are not expecting errors due to light obstruction) environment and you are willing to do some engineering (as what follows is only an outline) then consider using SPI to 1 wire bridge chips on both sides and using IR LED transmitters (software driven to transmit ASK type signals) and an IR ASK receivers (a device which usually contains an IR sensitive transistor, a band-pass filter and a PLL decoder - commonly found in remotely controlled appliances).  Again, this last bit is only a suggestion and a fair bit of engineering is needed to get it to work.  But, likely, far less then to implement the IrDA stack.

Comment: The link posted posted by the OP in a comment is to an NXP chip that is an I2C/SPI to IrDA bridge. It appears to implement everything itself.

Comment: @gbulmer, Wow - Totally missed that.  Interesting NXP.COM device! The sales pitch doesn't say (much) about the protocol.  But then, if Dirk Bruere is in control of both ends he can implement his own protocol.